# Mediation Analysis: Does the homoscedasticity postulate is respected? If not, what can we do to solve that problem?

Tags: variance, maximum-likelihood, bootstrap, heteroscedasticity, mediation

The purpose of my analyzes (with Rstudio) is to test the direct and indirect relations in a mediation model (to verify if the relationship between I_d and R_re_moy is mediated by U_moy). I_d is the independant variable, R_re_moy is the dependant variable and U_moy is the mediator. My variables are measured, not latents. My sample size is n=32 participants. But before testing my mediation model, I verified somes postulates. One postulate that does not seem to be respected is homoscedasticity.

```
reg<-lm(R_re_moy~I_d+U_moy, data = BDD)
library(olsrr)
ols_plot_resid_fit(reg)
```

[image]

I know that in order to respect the postulate of homoscedasticity, the residuals should distribute in an oval shape. If we consider that the scatterplot above demonstrate heteroscedasticity, what can I do to solve/attenuate that problem? Is there an robust estimator that I can use for that?
I want to clarifiy that there is not outliers in my sample.

Afterward,  I tested my mediation model by using the "MLR" estimator to verify the direct effects. To verify the indirect effect, I used the "ML" estimator, with boostraping.

```
#Direct effect
model<- lavaan::sem(model = 
                      "U_moy~meda*I_d
R_re_moy~medb*U_moy
R_re_moy~ dir*I_d
indirect := meda*medb
total := dir+indirect",
                    data = BDD,
                    estimator = "MLR",
                    missing = "fiml")

#Indirect effect
model<- lavaan::sem(model = 
                      "U_moy~meda*I_d
R_re_moy~medb*U_moy
R_re_moy~ dir*I_d
indirect := meda*medb
total := dir+indirect",
                    data = BDD,
                    estimator = "ML",
                    missing = "fiml",
                    se = "bootstrap",
                    bootstrap = 5000)
```

Does MLR estimator and the boostraping technique can be considered "robust" for heteroscedasticity? Or is it still a problem in my situation?

Thanks a lot!